# Execute Batch API for adding multiple users to multiple groups

Tags: google-api, google-directory-api

We are trying to add multiple Users to Multiple Groups through batch request

**Endpoint**

```
www.googleapis.com/batch/directory/v1
```

**Body**

```
--0056A000000MSKlQAO 

Content-Length:405 

Content-Type: application/http 

Content-id: 1 

Content-transfer-encoding: binary 

POST https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/{{groupKey}}/members

.

.

.

--0056A000000MSKlQAO
```

We are getting error `endpointConstraintMismatch` error

Reference

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-group-members#create_member

Can we add 5 different users to 5 different Groups at one go.

Comment: The error means **The request failed because it did not match the specified API. Check the value of the URL path to make sure it is correct.**

Comment: Yes thats clear from google api documentation. Can we add 5 different users to 5 different Groups at one go.